# Sync MySQL database from local to online

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization

I have two MySQL databases. One is in Local PC & another is in online server. Now I have to sync local database with online database. I use  curl to do this. Is there any better way to do this without losing any data from local DB to online DB? Any suggestion of any kind of tools or library to complete the sync process?

[image]

In my local DB I use trigger to track each insert & update for every tables. We don’t hard delete anything. A sync table is used to keep the trigger history.  Here is the screen-shot  of my ‘sync’ table.

Explanation of sync table:

1. id  -->  primary key of sync table
2. table_name --> name of the table in which an action(insert/update) occurred
3. pkey_column_name --> primary key container column name of the table (table_name)
4. row_id --> primary key of the table ( table_name)
5. type --> enum(insert,update)
6. status --> (synced/unsynced)

Based on this sync table I fetch all the data from local DB which are not synced before & submit a post request with those data to online DB using curl to insert & update the online DB. If this process will be success then the rows of the status column of sync table will be synced otherwise it will keep the default value unsynced.

Is this process is good enough for sync process? How can I make sure that all the data are transferred successfully & the data integrity also for large data? And what are the problems may occur with this process?

Answer (score 0):

In order to exchange info from or to a hosted server I´m prefer to use intermediate files like TXT or XML.

I´m assuming that your request has not need to be solved in real time (syncro) and it could support to be solved in minutes (asyncro).

One idea.

1. look inside Online DB for news and "export" new content to a TXT file.
2. move TXT to a local DB
3. run a query to syncro this content with local DB
4. run a query to get new content from local DB and export to a TXT file.
5. move TXT to a online DB
6. run a query to syncro this content with online DB

It is more difficult to explain than do.

In order to make a query you can use:
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1803-PHP-Synchronize-MySQL-database-copies.html

You have to create a cron to run this query each 5 minutes or time you want.

Also is very important to focus on new content: a well defined trigger that show which content is new or not is a baseline to be successful in this process.

I hope it fits for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP then here is a simple solution.

```
    include "sync.php";
    $sync = new SyncronizeDB();
    //serverSet(dbserver,user,password,db,table,index)  
    $sync->masterSet("localhost", "root", "", "localdatabase","localtable", "localtable.pk");
    $sync->slaveSet("onlinehostip", "username", "pass", "remotedbname", "remotetable", "remotetable.pk");
    $sync->slaveSyncronization();
```

You can download the sync.php file from [PHP CLASSES](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/4790-PHP-Synchronize-two-MySQL-databases.html#download)